# Wireless driver related warnings from kernel

Tags: drivers, kernel, broadcom

I am getting the current warning from the kernel:

```
[39513.661728] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[39513.661801] WARNING: CPU: 3 PID: 469 at /build/linux-hwe-eyfT8D/linux-hwe-4.8.0/net/wireless/sme.c:876 cfg80211_roamed+0x8a/0xa0 [cfg80211]
[39513.661804] Modules linked in: rfcomm ipt_MASQUERADE nf_nat_masquerade_ipv4 xfrm_user xfrm_algo iptable_nat nf_conntrack_ipv4 nf_defrag_ipv4 nf_nat_ipv4 xt_addrtype iptable_filter ip_tables xt_conntrack x_tables nf_nat nf_conntrack br_netfilter bridge stp llc aufs bnep nls_iso8859_1 hp_wmi sparse_keymap wl(POE) uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops snd_hda_codec_hdmi videobuf2_v4l2 videobuf2_core videodev btusb media btrtl snd_soc_skl intel_rapl snd_soc_skl_ipc snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_soc_sst_ipc snd_hda_codec_generic snd_soc_sst_dsp x86_pkg_temp_thermal snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_sst_match snd_soc_core snd_compress ac97_bus coretemp snd_pcm_dmaengine snd_hda_intel kvm_intel snd_hda_codec kvm snd_hda_core snd_hwdep snd_pcm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event irqbypass crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul
[39513.661908]  snd_rawmidi snd_seq ghash_clmulni_intel cfg80211 aesni_intel aes_x86_64 snd_seq_device lrw snd_timer glue_helper snd joydev input_leds serio_raw soundcore ablk_helper hci_uart btbcm cryptd btqca intel_cstate intel_rapl_perf ucsi btintel bluetooth dptf_power processor_thermal_device intel_soc_dts_iosf mei_me mei int3403_thermal int340x_thermal_zone shpchp intel_lpss_acpi hp_wireless intel_pch_thermal intel_lpss int3400_thermal mac_hid acpi_thermal_rel int3406_thermal tpm_crb acpi_pad nfsd auth_rpcgss nfs_acl lockd grace sunrpc parport_pc ppdev lp parport autofs4 i915 i2c_algo_bit drm_kms_helper syscopyarea psmouse sysfillrect sysimgblt fb_sys_fops r8169 drm mii ahci libahci wmi i2c_hid video hid fjes
[39513.662027] CPU: 3 PID: 469 Comm: wl_event_handle Tainted: P        W  OE   4.8.0-36-generic #36~16.04.1-Ubuntu
[39513.662031] Hardware name: HP HP 240 G5 Notebook PC/81DB, BIOS F.32 01/23/2018
[39513.662036]  0000000000000286 0000000053f314bd ffffa2671de5fdc0 ffffffffa2a2d7b3
[39513.662047]  0000000000000000 0000000000000000 ffffa2671de5fe00 ffffffffa268313b
[39513.662056]  0000036c00000008 ffffa26723675000 ffffa26722bab780 000000000000007c
[39513.662065] Call Trace:
[39513.662079]  [<ffffffffa2a2d7b3>] dump_stack+0x63/0x90
[39513.662089]  [<ffffffffa268313b>] __warn+0xcb/0xf0
[39513.662098]  [<ffffffffa268326d>] warn_slowpath_null+0x1d/0x20
[39513.662149]  [<ffffffffc07919aa>] cfg80211_roamed+0x8a/0xa0 [cfg80211]
[39513.662296]  [<ffffffffc0b850f5>] wl_notify_roaming_status+0xc5/0x140 [wl]
[39513.662429]  [<ffffffffc0b84740>] wl_event_handler+0x60/0x1e0 [wl]
[39513.662550]  [<ffffffffc0b846e0>] ? wl_notify_scan_status+0x330/0x330 [wl]
[39513.662559]  [<ffffffffa26a4008>] kthread+0xd8/0xf0
[39513.662572]  [<ffffffffa2e9679f>] ret_from_fork+0x1f/0x40
[39513.662581]  [<ffffffffa26a3f30>] ? kthread_create_on_node+0x1e0/0x1e0
[39513.662586] ---[ end trace e743c7683564ee43 ]-
```

The wireless card in my laptop is a Broadcom card.  The specific device information (from `lspci`) is:

```
Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n (rev 01)
```

I have following kernel installed:

```
Linux prashant-HP-240-G5-Notebook-PC 4.8.0-36-generic #36~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Sun Feb 5 09:39:57 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Whenever I get this warning, I lose my internet connection, and cannot reach anywhere, even to other devices on my LAN.

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Which actual Ubuntu release are you using?  You can get this information from `lsb_release -a`

Comment: No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
Release: 16.04
Codename: xenial

Comment: Interestingly, I have the same issue. I am using a MacBook Pro with Linux mint as the OS. My NIC is also Broadcom. The warning messages are similar to yours. Do you find a solution yet?